# how to remove space and special character from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

*i have a list like*:

```
['BOOL_CONST_GROUP                                                                                                        |                |\n', 
 'BOOL_GROUP                                                                                                              |                |\n', 
 'BOOL_TEXT_GROUP                                                                                                         |                |\n', 
 'FIXED_DATA_GROUP                                                                                                        |                |\n', 
 'PATTERN_PF0                                                                                                             |                |\n', 
 'BOOL_Partition                                                                                            |                |\n', 
 'VVS_Data_Z_Partition                                                                                                    |                |\n']
```

*i need this list to convert like* :

```
['BOOL_CONST_GROUP', 
 'BOOL_GROUP ', 
 'BOOL_TEXT_GROUP ', 
 'FIXED_DATA_GROUP', 
 'PATTERN_PF0 ', 
 'BOOL_Partition', 
 'VVS_Data_Z_Partition ']
```

*I tried this*:

```
l1 = [i for i in l1 if i]
```

*Also i tried this* *but not working*

```
''.join(e for e in l1[1] if e.isalnum())
```

Comment: l1 = [i.split('')[0] for i in l1], use like this, you find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
a = ['BOOL_CONST_GROUP                                                                                                        
|                |\n', 
 'BOOL_GROUP                                                                                                              
|                |\n', 
'BOOL_TEXT_GROUP                                                                                                         
|                |\n', 
 'FIXED_DATA_GROUP                                                                                                        
|                |\n', 
 'PATTERN_PF0                                                                                                             
|                |\n', 
 'BOOL_Partition                                                                                            
|                |\n', 
 'VVS_Data_Z_Partition                                                                                                    
|                |\n']

a = [i.split('')[0] for i in a]
print(a)
```

The output is as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import re
    x=['BOOL_CONST_GROUP                                                                                                        |                |\n', 
     'BOOL_GROUP                                                                                                              |                |\n', 
     'BOOL_TEXT_GROUP                                                                                                         |                |\n', 
     'FIXED_DATA_GROUP                                                                                                        |                |\n', 
     'PATTERN_PF0                                                                                                             |                |\n', 
     'BOOL_Partition                                                                                            |                |\n', 
     'VVS_Data_Z_Partition                                                                                                    |                |\n']
    
     x=[re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+','',i) for i in x]
     print(x)
```